# What are some good preparatory books for Putnam? I don't mean practice or problem solving, but rather to learn the material that is tested on Putnam.

Tags: contest-math, book-recommendation

I want to learn the math topics that are tested on Putnam Please recommend some good books that I can use for self study. for practice I have "Putnam and beyond". but I am a first yeat student and don't know a lot and professors are terible here so I have to rely on other material..Thanks

Edit: I know there is no single book that will cover everything. I am asking for books on different topics. I already have Calculus by Spivak and Analysis by Paugh but I need books that cover other topics. Thanks again.

Comment: For the close-voter: I'm not sure this counts as seeking personal advice. In fact it looks like a standard book-recommendation type of question (hence I added the tag)

Comment: Putnam problems are notorious for being very non-simple, even for working mathematicians, so they often can't come up with a simple solution. So in a way there aren't single books to teach all that's required. A typical mathematician has already read many.

Comment: At UCLA they have two putnam classes, Math 100 and 101. Frequently it is taught by Professor Manolescu, who was in the top 5 for 3 years on the Putnam. Here are are his syllabuses for those classes which include textbooks: https://www.math.ucla.edu/ugrad/courses/math/100, https://www.math.ucla.edu/ugrad/courses/math/101